# Imprimir registros con el mes mas reciente por trabajador PHP

Tags: php

Requiero generar un txt con los los registros más recientes de un trabajador en PHP.

Hago la consulta de los trabajadores e imprimo con fopen. Hasta ahí todo bien.
Pero solo necesito la información de la ultima fecha que tenga

Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
$str_queryCon="SELECT trabajadorID, nombreTrabajador, sBaseCt, fechaInicial
               FROM Gdt.dbo.integrados
               order BY  trabajadorid, fechaInicial DESC";
//echo "CONSULTA CAMPOS ".$str_queryCon."<br>";
$queryCon = sqlsrv_query($connFac, $str_queryCon);


if (file_exists($nombre_tabla.'.txt')){
        unlink($nombre_tabla.'.txt');
}

while($rsCon=sqlsrv_fetch_array($queryCon)){


    $trabajadorID = $rsCon['trabajadorID'];
    $nombreTrabajador = $rsCon['nombreTrabajador'];
    $sBaseCt = $rsCon['sBaseCt'];
    $fechaInicial = $rsCon['fechaInicial'];

        $imprime=$trabajadorID.$tabulador.$nombreTrabajador.$tabulador.$sBaseCt.$tabulador.$fechaInicial.$salto;
    

    
    if (file_exists($nombre_tabla.'.txt')){
    $archivo = fopen($nombre_tabla.'.txt', "a");
    fwrite($archivo, "$imprime");
    fclose($archivo);
    }
    else{

    $archivo = fopen($nombre_tabla.'.txt', "w");
    fwrite($archivo, "$imprime");
    fclose($archivo);
       }
}
```

Pero obtengo toda la información no solo el ultimo registro

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que necesito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ojala me puedan ayudar.

Saludos.

Comment: Puedes modificar tu query para obtener el registro mas actual de cada trabajador.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta consulta que hace un **INNER JOIN** para seleccionar el máximo valor de la fecha de cada trabajador.

```
SELECT s1.trabajadorID, s1.nombreTrabajador, s1.sBaseCt, s1.fechaInicial
from Gdt.dbo.integrados as s1
inner join
(
  select max(fechaInicial) fecha,
    trabajadorID
  from Gdt.dbo.integrados
  group by trabajadorID
) s2
  on s1.trabajadorID = s2.trabajadorID
  and s1.fechaInicial = s2.fecha;
```